# Spring Boot url mappings order for controllers and static pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application which is meant to serve both static and controller based (`ModelAndView`) pages. Problem is that a controller can serve something like `/{string}` and a static page must be served with `/test`.

The problem is that the controller mapping takes precedence, and I need to avoid that. If the user hits `/test`, he must be forwarded to the `test.html` static page.

I tried to use the order property of **ViewControllerRegistry** in this way, with no success:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("forward:/test.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE); // but I tried with 0 and -1 as well: annotated controllers should have order equals to 0
    }

}
```

This is my **SpringBootApplication** class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class VipApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VipApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And this is the **controller** code:

```
@Controller
public class VipController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{string}")
    public ModelAndView vip(@PathVariable("string") String string) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("mypage");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

How can I reorder the mappings to make sure static pages are considered before annotated controllers?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure, but) I suggest to override [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) method and configure order of resource handler by invoking [`ResourceHandlerRegistry.setOrder()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html#setOrder-int-)